# How to get HTML hidden code in a Facebook page

Tags: c#, facebook, html-parsing

I noticed that in HTML Facebook code page some posts are hidden and they show only when you scroll the page.

Is it possible to get all text posts in a Facebook page, even the text hidden by the scroll function? (I tried with a classic WebRequest, WebResponse and ReadStream of response but there isn't the scrollable code )
Should I download a specific library for this task?

Comment: You should not scrape pages, but use the API to access information.

Answer (score 0):

you cant't do that because when you scrolling its get the data to view .